# Create Azure Storage Account with Powershell Fails

Tags: powershell, azure, accounts, name, azure-storage

I'm trying to create a **storage account** but I get the following error:

"New-AzStorageAccount : The resource type '**checkNameAvailability**' could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Storage' for 
api version '2018-11-01'. The supported api-versions are '2018-07-01,2018-03-01-preview,2018-02-01,2017-10-01,2017-06-01,2016-
12-01,2016-07-01,2016-05-01,2016-01-01,2015-06-15,2015-05-01-preview'."

As you can tell I'm using Az Modules. Is there something additional I need to install for the checknameavailability feature to work? Here is my **powershell version info**:
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision

---

5      1      17134  590

I've tried using the same command with AzureRm.. but same error. I don't have a much Powershell experience so I'm lost on how to fix this. I'd appreciate any help/guidance on resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Checked the Azure Rest API call and powershell for `checkNameAvailability` it's working fine.

[image: RestAPI]

[image: PowerShell]

You need to check on the azure module version not the PowerShell version, i will check specifically the Storage Module in the Azure Module.

[image: Storage Module]

Comment: I'm using the Az modules, but when I try running it i get the same api issue. My api version '2018-11-01' but The supported api-versions are '2018-07-01,2018-03-01-preview,2018-02-01,201
7-10-01,2017-06-01,2016-12-01,2016-07-01,2016-05-01,2016-01-01,2015-06-15,2015-05-01-preview'. Is it possible to downgrade my api version or something?

Comment: You can check the module version on AZ module too https://i.imgur.com/nFjFcSz.png.  If you are on the latest and still getting issue try running the `Get-AzStorageAccountNameAvailability` command with `-verbose`. `Get-AzStorageAccountNameAvailability -Name serverfaultstr336 -Verbose`

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you don’t have the “old” AzureRM module installed when you are using AZ module. I’ve had similar errors with other Cmdlets until I uninstalled AzureRM
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/uninstall-az-ps?view=azps-1.7.0#uninstall-the-azurerm-module

```
Uninstall-AzureRM
```

Comment: I uninstalled the Rm modules and I'm using Az. Its complaining my api version isn't supported. It's 2018-11-01 which is newer that the supported 2018-07-01,2018-03-01-preview,2018-02-01, etc.